# mysql add constraint check column in list

Tags: mysql, list, constraints

I try to add an constraint for an exited column in a table, here is my code:

```
ALTER TABLE `mdt_test`.`product` add constraint IsBackOrdered_limited_n_y check(IsBackOrdered in ('n', 'y'));
```

system action output for my code:

```
0 row(s) affected Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0    0.016 sec
```

I believe it should be correct but once I run this code it still go though:

```
update `mdt_test`.`product` set IsBackOrdered = 'U' where ProductID = '100004';
```

system action output:

```
1 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0  0.015 sec
```

the constraint should only allows the value existed in list ('n', 'y'), all other value should not allowable I have no idea what is going on.

Please give me some help for setup the constraint and I don't want to use foreign key, thanks.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Older versions allow check constraints to be defined (without throwing an error) but never enforce them.

Comment: Hello @stickybit my SQL version is '5.7.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1'

Comment: Yup, that's to old. Upgrade to the latest version or directly to a more capable DBMS.